# What can I do to have the component render once?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I have a panel that has a menu.When we select any of the menus, they open in the tab.

```
const openTab = (state, action) => {
  let newOpenedTabs = [];
  if (action.tab.singleTab) {
    const current = state.openedTabs.findIndex(
      (t) => t.title === action.tab.title
    );
    if (current !== -1) {
      newOpenedTabs = [
        ...state.openedTabs.map((t) => ({ ...t, selected: false })),
      ];
      newOpenedTabs[current].selected = true;
    } else
      newOpenedTabs = [
        ...state.openedTabs.map((t) => ({ ...t, selected: false })),
        { ...action.tab, selected: true },
      ];
  } else
    newOpenedTabs = [
      ...state.openedTabs.map((t) => ({ ...t, selected: false })),
      { ...action.tab, selected: true },
    ];
  return updateObject(state, {
    openedTabs: newOpenedTabs,
  });
};
```

And this is how I call the method

```
 const getComponent = (Component, props) => {
    return <Component {...props} />;
  };

 props.openedTabs.map((tab, i) => (
                  <TabPanel
                    value={props.openedTabs.findIndex((t) => t.selected)}
                    index={i}
                    key={i}
                    className={classes.tabPanelItem}
                  >
                   getComponent(tab.component, tab.props)
                  </TabPanel>
                ))
              )
```

But the problem I have is that when I switch between tabs, component renders twice.
What can I do to not render again?

Comment: Remove the [StrictMode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html)?!

Comment: Can you tell me how to do this?

Comment: Do you mean this? `   <React.StrictMode>
      <Component {...props} />
    </React.StrictMode>`

Comment: Yes. `<React.StrictMode> <Component {...props} /> </React.StrictMode>` ---> `<Component {...props} />`

Comment: it not working.

Comment: Can you create a demo on codesandbox and share the link?